# Wordpress admin failure

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am trying to login to a wordpress admin at http://www.kzoomarketing.com/tascott/wp-login.php

I get this message:

```
Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected. in /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-login.php on line 361

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-login.php:361) in /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-login.php on line 363

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-login.php:361) in /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 669

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-login.php:361) in /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 670

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-login.php:361) in /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 671

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-login.php:361) in /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 673

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-login.php:361) in /home/absbm/public_html/tascott/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 866
```

I have removed the white space at the end of login.php and still recieve this error.

I have also looked at line 361 and compared the file to other wordpress installations and do not see any issues.

Any help with this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'had the same issue and i solve the problem whith this :

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-header-1

joshfraz Posted 4 years ago

I had this problem too. It turned out that I had an extra space at the end of my siteurl option. Once I removed the space it worked fine.

So in your WP database, chech in wp_options > siturl and delete any extra space or newline in the value field.

Some other users look to have utf8 BOM code issue if the first way don't fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Often these kind of errors pop up when you have a file which contains white space before or after the `<?php` and `?>`.

If you got a plugin or something that you customized, make sure that there is no whitespace before the `<?php`. The `?>` can be usually omitted entirely to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change your core files.

I suspect one of your plugin files causes the problem, try disabling them one by one, if you find the one remove the last ?> in the offending file.

There is also a plugin which goes by all your plugins and then deletes all whitespaces at the end.